# Oscilloscope Trace Appear Delayed

Tags: oscilloscope, delay, trace, time

I saw a thing on my GDS-1052-U oscilloscope: if I set the time base to 25mS/div there appear a delay of the signal on the screen. So, when I rotate the knob for the time base to 25mS/div, there is a delay until the trace appear on the screen. If I set the time base to 5mS/div there is almost no delay. If I set the knob for 10mS/div the delay is smaller than the delay for 25mS/div. This happens on both channels. The probe is not connected to any signal source while I do these things. The voltage/division is 20mV/div.
Is that normal ?

Comment: You should include a screenshot so we can see what you're doing. Accurate delays can only be measured **between** two traces, not how long it takes for the trace to appear on the screen, that actually means **nothing**. How fast the trace appears on the screen also depends on when the scope actually triggers and how long it takes to process the data. Maybe the amount of samples changed between timebase settings so processing takes longer.

Comment: This is not unusual at slow timebase settings; does the status show 'untriggered roll' or 'auto roll'?

Comment: I made a video @Bimpelrekkie https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqC2zcKXTrY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @oldfart  The trigger point is on the screen. It can be seen on the right side of the screen.

Comment: My comment came at the same time as you link to the video. I'll delete it.

Comment: So I watched the video: what you see is **normal** you're not feeding the scope a "proper" signal so triggering is "random". You cannot and should not draw any conclusions based on what you see (how fast the trace appears) because it means **nothing**. Only when you use the scope **properly** conclusions can be drawn. At this moment you're not using the scope "properly" so stop drawing conclusions about delays etc.

Comment: *The probe is not connected to any signal source while I do these things* Hmm, now i see that, so what's the **point** of this exercise then? There's a square wave output for probe calibration on this scope, connect the probe to that and experiment. An unconnected probe does not give any meaningful signal.

Comment: You should adjust the **horizontal position** control so that the trigger point is *in the exact middle of the screen*. Then, when you switch to a different, faster timebase, the trigger point will *always* stay at the same middle-screen point, and you won't get a sweep delay.

Comment: I made a video with the calibration signal @Bimpelrekkie https://youtu.be/-ZBCNYcEkYE I noticed that there is a delay from the moment I connect the probe to the calibration signal and the moment when the signal appears on the screen. Also there is a delay from the moment I disconnect the probe and the moment when the signal disapears from the screen.

Comment: Pretty normal for cheap scopes, they take their time to setup